# Detecting the number of processors

Tags: .net, wmi, cpu, environment

How do you detect the number of physical processors/cores in .net?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
System.Environment.ProcessorCount
```

returns the number of logical processors

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx

For physical processor count you'd probably need to use WMI - the following metadata is supported in XP/Win2k3 upwards (Functionality enabled in SP's prior to Vista/Win2k8).

> **Win32_ComputerSystem.NumberOfProcessors** returns physical count
>
> **Win32_ComputerSystem.NumberOfLogicalProcessors** returns logical (duh!)

Be cautious that HyperThreaded CPUs appear identical to multicore'd CPU's yet the performance characteristics are *very* different.

To check for HT-enabled CPUs examine each instance of Win32_Processor and compare these two properties.

> **Win32_Processor.NumberOfLogicalProcessors**
>
> **Win32_Processor.NumberOfCores**

On multicore systems these are typically the same the value.

Also, be aware of systems that may have multiple **Processor Groups**, which is often seen on computers with a large number of processors. By default [.Net will only using the first processor group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965962/c-sharp-environment-processorcount-does-not-always-return-the-full-number-of-log) - which means that by default, threads will utilize only CPUs from the first processor group, and `Environment.ProcessorCount` will return only the number of CPUs in this group. According to [Alastair Maw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965962/c-sharp-environment-processorcount-does-not-always-return-the-full-number-of-log/30456753#30456753), this behavior can be changed by altering the app.config as follows:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true"/>
      <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should note, it's supported only in XP SP3/Win2k3 and upwards.

Answer (score 12):

While `Environment.ProcessorCount` will indeed get you the number of virtual processors in the system, that may not be the number of processors available to your process.  I whipped up a quick little static class/property to get exactly that:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

/// <summary>
/// Provides a single property which gets the number of processor threads
/// available to the currently executing process.
/// </summary>
internal static class ProcessInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of processors.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The number of processors.</value>
    internal static uint NumberOfProcessorThreads
    {
        get
        {
            uint processAffinityMask;

            using (var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                processAffinityMask = (uint)currentProcess.ProcessorAffinity;
            }

            const uint BitsPerByte = 8;
            var loop = BitsPerByte * sizeof(uint);
            uint result = 0;

            while (--loop > 0)
            {
                result += processAffinityMask & 1;
                processAffinityMask >>= 1;
            }

            return (result == 0) ? 1 : result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering my question in a different post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134566/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-available-processors-for-my-application

Comment: +1 not having all cores available can happen in quite a few scenarios, such as ASP.NET code in a "web-garden" configuration.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. `ProcessorAffinity` gets the "the processors on which the threads in this process can be scheduled to run," not the number of physical processors. On my Core i7, (4 cores w/ HT), `ProcessorAffinity` returns 255, which means 8 processors, which is not the number of physical processors.

Answer (score 4):

This actually varies quite a bit depending on the target platform. Stephbu's answer will work great on XP SP3 and newer.

If you are targeting older platforms, you may want to check out [this article](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/01/counting-processors-in-net-the-pros-and-cons-of-five-different-methods.aspx). I wrote it about half a year ago and in it I discuss several different ways to do this as well as the individual pros and cons of each method.

You may also want to check out [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/countingprocessors.aspx) if you are interested in differentiating shadow cores from hyperthreading from real ones.

Comment: Hey Rick there was a HF for XP SP2 to support the same objects
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936235

Answer (score 3):

System.Environment.ProcessorCount is what you need

Comment: posted Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS") first, but then I realized it was already parsed in a separate property

Comment: ProcessorCount returns the number of logical processors, not the number of physical processors or even the number of cores. Not what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 3):

Environment.ProcessorCount

EDIT: available in .NET 2.0, not in .NET 1.1

Comment: Doesn't return the number of cores however.  Only logical CPUs

Answer (score 2):

Environment.ProcessorCount will also include any hyperthreaded processors.

There is no way (at least up through Windows 2003) to distinguish a hyperthreaded processor from one with two cores.

Comment: Not quite true - there were several service packs to enable WMI CPU metadata for both XP and Win2k3

Comment: Fair enough -- when I needed to do it I was wanting to simply use the Win32 APIs not dig through WMI (especially if I had to know which processor had which features)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough rep for the wiki, but note that in addition to XPSP2, Windows 2003 Server SP1 and SP2 also need a hotfix to enable this functionality:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932370

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to access comprehensive processor information. For example, you can run the following command to get the number of CPU cores:

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root\CIMV2 -class Win32_Processor -Property NumberOfCores
```

It's much easier to research WMI when using some kind of explorer tool. So, I can suggest using WMI browsing tool (e.g. [WMIExplorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/) or [WMI CIM Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24045)) to explore WMI classes, properties and methods.