# How do I tell if the machine my program is running on uses hyperthreading? (C#)

Tags: c#, hyperthreading

I have some code that needs to know how many actual cores are available on my particular machine, and whether or not Hyperthreading is enabled.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Update: The machines are a mix of XP and Vista

Update: Accessing 'Win32_Processor.NumberOfCores' or 'Win32_Processor.NumberOfLogicalProcessors' throws an exception (a ManagmentException with the message "Not Found") on one of the machines (but not all of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Vista and higher you can use GetLogicalProcessorInformation via PInvoke to get the number of logical processor units.

On Windows XP there's no way via C# to reliably differentiate hyper-threading from other multi-processor/core configurations. The WMI solution that someone posted will class multi-core processors as hyper-threaded.

Prior to Vista the only reliable means is to check the CPUID of the processor. To use this you could create a native DLL that can be called from your managed code. The following Intel code [sample](http://www.mail-archive.com/redhat-devel-list@redhat.com/msg06114.html) would be a good starting point.

Comment: The link appears to be broken

Comment: I thought HT would be 2 logical processor, 1 physical and a dual core would show 2 logical and 2 physical processors.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to the first question at least: *Environment.ProcessorCount* should return the number of cores on the machine.

**Edit**: [Here](http://community.devpinoy.org/blogs/cvega/archive/2006/04/07/2658.aspx)'s a non-WMI-based method of checking for whether Hyperthreading is enabled (not that it's any nicer necessarily). Also see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/countingprocessors.aspx?df=100&forumid=149329&exp=0&select=1577587) article.

Answer (score 1):

System.Environment.ProcessorCount will tell you how many cores exist on the machine the code is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Environment.ProcessorCount property, it will return an integer, as far as HyperThreading, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverflow question 188503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188503/detecting-the-number-of-processors) has the information you need ...

Quoting the top answer on that question:

```
System.Environment.ProcessorCount
```

returns the number of logical processors (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx?ppud=4))

To distinguish between Hyperthreaded and separate cores, sounds as though you need a bit of WMI.

Answer (score 0):

[GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx) is sufficient for the HT aspect but sadly it is only available in XP SP3, 64bit XP/Vista/Server 2003 (and I believe is is slightly broken pre vista)

[Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/CommentView,guid,e1791031-e477-4b8c-b342-933f198ef137.aspx) wrapped this in c# but has not yet released the source, though Mark Russinovich has released the tool (Coreinfo) he created with it, likely you can decompile that to see the code.