# How to get the number of processors on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: count, wmi, processor

How can I find the number CPUs on 64 bit window 2003 servers?  The answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188503/detecting-the-number-of-processors) did not work.  Using Win32_ComputerSystem.NumberOfProcessors returns none.

I would prefer a way to do it using WMI if possible.  I have a script that already his all the machines I need this info from grabbing disk info.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

how about giving Win32_Processor a try

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")    
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
```

Comment: Close. Here is the script I used:

import wmi
servers = ['xxx','yyy', 'TRIGOLDDB']
for servername in servers:
    connection = wmi.connect_server (server=servername)  #, user="tim", password="secret")
    c = wmi.WMI (wmi=connection)
    print servername
    
    for proc in c.Win32_Processor():
        # print '{0:>10} {1} {2:3}GBs   Free: {3:3}GBs ({4:5.2f}% free)'.format(disk.VolumeName,disk.Caption, (long(disk.Size)/1024/1024/1024), (long(disk.FreeSpace)/1024/1024/1024), (100.0 * long (disk.FreeSpace) / long (disk.Size)))
        print proc.name
    print

It lists 8 should be 2 (2 quad).

Comment: maybe you should post it not in comment section so that formatting is preserved, for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: I took your suggestion - below.  Formatting still a little off :-(

Answer (score 1):

Close. Here is the script I used:

```
import wmi

servers = ['XXX','YYY']

for servername in servers:
    connection = wmi.connect_server (server=servername)
    c = wmi.WMI (wmi=connection)
    print servername

    for proc in c.Win32_Processor():
        print proc.name
    print
```

The output is:

> XXX
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> YYY
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor
>
> Intel(R) Pentium(R) III Xeon processor

I should just see two processecors for each server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a WMI query.  The following script puts the SocketDesignation name for each logical CPU in a database table for the list of servers in the csv file.  Once the table is populated running the following query will give you a count of physical and logical processors:

```
select servername, COUNT(cpuname) 'LogicalCPUCount', COUNT(distinct cpuname) 'PhysicalCPUCount'
from tmp_cpu
group by servername
```

*****  WMI script - you will need to adjust connections and create the tmp_cpu table prior to running *****

```
$query = "delete sqlserverinventory.dbo.tmp_cpu"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance "xxxxxxxx"

 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select servername from sqlserverinventory.dbo.server where servername in (select servername from sqlserverinventory.dbo.vw_Instance_Autoload);" -ServerInstance "xxxxxxxx" | out-file -filepath "v:\scripts\server_list.csv"

 (Get-Content v:\scripts\server_list.csv) | where {$_.readcount -gt 3} | Set-Content v:\scripts\server_list.csv

$servers = Get-Content "V:\scripts\server_list.csv"
## $servers = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select servername from sqlserverinventory.dbo.vw_Instance_Autoload;" -ServerInstance "xxxxxxxx"

foreach ($server in $servers){

    $server = $server.Trim()

    $SQLServices = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -query "SELECT SocketDesignation FROM Win32_Processor where CPUStatus=1 or CPUStatus=4" 

    forEach ($SQLService in $SQLServices) {

        $PhysicalCPU = $SQLService.SocketDesignation

        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO sqlserverinventory.dbo.tmp_cpu (ServerName,CPUName) VALUES('$server','$PhysicalCPU')"

        ## "sql - $insert_query" 
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $insert_query -ServerInstance "xxxxxxxx"
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtObjects = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");

        foreach (var item in mgmtObjects.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NumberOfProcessors:" + item.Properties["NumberOfProcessors"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("NumberOfLogicalProcessors:" + item.Properties["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"].Value);
        }
```