# Is there a way to reliably detect the total number of CPU cores?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cpu-cores

I need a reliable way to detect how many CPU cores are on a computer.  I am creating a numerically intense simulation C# application and want to create the maximum number of running threads as cores.  I have tried many of the methods suggested around the internet like Environment.ProcessorCount, using WMI, this code: http://blogs.adamsoftware.net/Engine/DeterminingthenumberofphysicalCPUsonWindows.aspx   None of them seem to think a AMD X2 has two cores.  Any ideas?

Edit: it appears that Environment.ProcessorCount is returning the correct number.  It's on a intel CPU with hyperthreading that is returning the wrong number.  A signle core with hyperthreading is returning 2, when it should only be 1.

Comment: Your link is not working atm...

Comment: How many processors do you see in Taskmgr.exe, Performance tab?

Comment: The link was working the other day.

Comment: I can see two in the performance tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Detecting the number of processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188503/detecting-the-number-of-processors)

Alternatively, use the `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()` Win32 API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That first link has all of the information that I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

From what I can tell, `Environment.ProcessorCount` may return an incorrect value when running under WOW64 (as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS) because the P/Invoke signature it relies on uses [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381.aspx) instead of [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340.aspx). This seems like an *obvious* issue, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't have been resolved by this point.

Try this and see if it resolves the issue:

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SYSTEM_INFO
    {
        public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
        public ushort wReserved;
        public uint dwPageSize;
        public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
        public UIntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
        public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
        public uint dwProcessorType;
        public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
        public ushort wProcessorLevel;
        public ushort wProcessorRevision;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);
}

public static int ProcessorCount
{
    get
    {
        NativeMethods.SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo = new NativeMethods.SYSTEM_INFO();
        NativeMethods.GetNativeSystemInfo(ref lpSystemInfo);
        return (int)lpSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the correct processor count, AMD X2 is a true multi-core processor.  An Intel hyperthreaded core is treated by Windows as a muti-core CPU.  You can find out whether or not hyperthreading is used with WMI, [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx), NumberOfCores vs NumberOfLogicalProcessors.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable ?

Comment: This shows 8 on my i7, so hyperthreading cores are counted there