# QThread::idealThreadCount() returns the wrong answer, how to solve it?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a workstation with two E5-2679 CPU and it has 88 logical cores. But now I find

```
QThread::idealThreadCount()
```

only gives `32`. 
What's wrong with the function? I uses qtthreadpool and I don't want to change the code. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

The Qt version is 5.7 and compiler is mingw32. 
OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Is this your process https://ark.intel.com/products/91751 ?

Comment: Yes the processor is Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2679 v4

Comment: The ideal thread count could also be the physical core number. Logical processors allow fast context switching, but counting primes in a range e.g. might be faster with fewer threads, without any context switching at all, since it probably doesn't have to wait for external resources when everything can be calculated using only the processor registers.

Comment: @phi1010 Yes, you are right. I changed compiler to msvc2017 and it returned 44, which is the number of physical core.

Answer (score 2):

Qt on Windows [uses `GetSystemInfo`](https://fossies.org/linux/qt-everywhere-opensource-src/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp#l_430) to get the number of processors, which however [is capped to 32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688126/214671) for 32 bit processes, essentially because many APIs related to the number of processes (such as setting the affinity mask) use a 32-bit bitmask, and exposing a larger number of cores could lead older programs to unexpected results in manipulating them.

You'll have to implement the workaround described in the linked answer in your code, or patch the Qt build you are using to use `GetNativeSystemInfo` even on non-WinRT builds (although I'm not really sure it's safe - if they changed it only for WinRT builds maybe other stuff can break?). All in all, a simpler alternative may be to just build your application for 64 bit processors - besides this fix, you are probably going to get better performance thanks to the greater number of registers, availability of newer instructions and so on.

Finally, notice that if you go beyond 64 cores [stuff starts to become more complicated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed compiler to msvs2017 64bit, and it returned 44.

Comment: @nick0x01: great, if my answer helped you solve your problem you may consider upvoting and accepting it (thank you!) :-)