# Get total count of actual processor cores without Hyperthreading

Tags: c#, intel

I'm looking for a way to get the total number of actual processor cores, as everything I found (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)) returns the number of cores plus Intel's Hyperthreading technology, i.e. I'm shown 8 cores for my i7 6700K, while the processor only has `4 actual cores`. As far as I know, this only applies to Intel processors featuring the Hyperthreading Technology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reliably detect the total number of CPU cores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575472/is-there-a-way-to-reliably-detect-the-total-number-of-cpu-cores)

Comment: Actually it's already in the answer you link to

Comment: @ThomasWeller Why would I post if the answer was already given beforehand?

Comment: Second piece of code in highest voted, accepted answer:  `new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get() [...] int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString())`

Comment: I saw this, but it didn't work out for me (I later found why). Coincidentally, I did some research and stumbled upon akin code, which I transcribed to LINQ, eventually being the same.

Comment: Thanks to anyone for downvoting this, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself (using Linq). Alas, the code is not the fastest in speed terms. Reference `System.Management` and you're good to go:

```
var processorCoreCount = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Sum(item => int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString()));
```

Comment: @Picnic8 No, it was not. I posted the solution before ANY comment was published. Besides, he quoted something from an article I (!!!) referenced initially.