# c# Environment.ProcessorCount does not always return the full number of Logical Processor, why?

Tags: c#, cpu-cores, hyperthreading

On my machine, windows 7 - Enterprise with 1 x Intel Xeon E5-1660 0 @ 3.30Ghz (6 cores/cpu with Hyper Threading activated), Environment.ProcessorCount return 12 which is exact.

On a Windows Server 2012 with 2 x Intel Xeon E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz (14 cores/cpu with Hyper Threading activated(I think because task manager show: 2 sockets, 28 cores, 56 logical processors)), Environment.ProcessorCount return 28 which appears to us as wrong because 2x14x2 = 56.

Why on Windows Server 2012 c# method Environment.ProcessorCount does not return the proper number of logical processors?

As Additional information, environment variables are as follows:
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=28

[image: TaskManager]

**Update 2015-05-26:**

There is a more details/reasons of this related bug in my other question: [Unable to use more than one processor group for my threads in a C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098082/unable-to-use-more-than-one-processor-group-for-my-threads-in-a-c-sharp-app). Mainly I think that C# does only use one processor group. What's werid was that on our server, there was 2 processor groups although there was only 56 logical processors. But this [HP  CUSTOMER ADVISORY](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04650594) explain why our server bios configuration were inducing windows in error.

Comment: I'm surprised that `Environment.PermissionAccess` is giving you any CPU information :-) I can't even find it documented.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question title... I used the wrong method name. I'm sorry. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There may be a hint in the docs:

"If the current machine contains multiple processor groups, this property returns the number of logical processors **that are available** for use by the common language runtime (CLR)."

Could that be the issue here?

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Found something else interesting:

By default, the pool is restricted to a single processor group (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503(v=vs.85).aspx), and thus to 64 cores.  However, in .NET 4.5 you can set the Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true" flag.

[MSDN Forum Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/68c9984f-b7d1-46e1-a50c-8c87c4622b80/how-many-processor-cores-does-the-task-scheduler-support?forum=parallelextensions)

Comment: Yes it could be... but that's what I'm looking for. An explanation why the available number is less than the full amount? ... A license problem, a windows setting, windows normal behavior???

Comment: I wonder if the CLR either doesn't by default, or isn't capable of picking up on a second physical CPU?  I'm no expert in this area, but I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @user2366842, I agree, I wonder if it is the case (I thought it could be), I have no idea, I searched without success the reason why?

Comment: @Doug Dawson, your new found seems really interesting... I will have to test that today. I do not have access to that server directly. I  will be back soon with more info on the results (up to now, you seems to have found the solution to my problem)! I'm getting back soon...

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. Thanks a lots !!! Just FYI: I opened another question at Microsoft because Thread_UseAllCpuGroups does not work in my cases. I hope I will get a valid answer. Link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a871373d-e90d-4e26-bac1-0c45fd2f9d8e/unable-to-use-more-than-one-processor-group-for-my-threads-in-a-c-app?forum=parallelextensions

Comment: Did you also turn on GCCpuGroup and gcServer? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665638(v=vs.110).aspx says that you need all three.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the MSDN docs on <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665638(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to set up the following to have all the CPU groups seen and used:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true"/>
      <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I already did it. I added an update to my question because I received a lots of feedback from HP regarding this problem (added in another StackOverflow question)

Answer (score 0):

Check your system NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable. That's what method returns. See MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (permission section).

Comment: I know but it does not answer the reason why I only have the half. I want a documentation that says why I only have the half of it. If it is really because Environment.ProcessorCount does not take in account the second CPU then I will use that. But if I only see half of it because of a Windows Server setting, it would not be logical to multiply by the number of cpu.

Comment: For your information, your link is to version 4 of the framework. In version 4.5 the information about the environment variable has been removed and for one good reason: that is not true. I changed the environment variable and run my app and still see only half of logical processors (all in the same environment - same cmd prompt). But thanks for trying.