# Deciding MaxDegreeOfParallelism based on number of cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach, cpu-cores

I need to restore vm groups in parallel, for which I'm using a parallel foreach loop. I also want to use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to limit the number of threads. Since mine is a CPU bound operation, I believe the maximum number of threads should equal the number of cores.

*Does the number of threads depend on the actual number of cores or also on the number of logical processors?*
*Are there any other factors that this number could depend on? Is there a way other than trial-and-error to test this?*

Also, is this the relation between logical processors and actual cores:

**(# of logical processors) = (# of cores) * (# of threads per core)**

Comment: _"Does the number of threads depend on the actual number of cores or also on the number of logical processors?"_ -- the number of threads depends on how many threads _your code_ decides should run. So, neither of those. Certain CPU designs can theoretically run more than one thread concurrently. See duplicate for that explanation.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965962/c-sharp-environment-processorcount-does-not-always-return-the-full-number-of-log for a potential pitfall in determining your desired concurrency degree.

Comment: Have you tried not setting it and letting the scheduler decide?

Comment: You are probably overthinking it. Just configure your parallel loop with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` and you'll be OK, provided that the workload [is CPU-bound and not I/O-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean). You should definitely configure the `Parallel.ForEach` loop, and [not rely on the default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261010/multiple-parallel-foreach-loops-in-net/66263583#66263583), which is to use the `ThreadPool` saturation (starvation) as the throttling mechanism.